# Grails -- check whether the request is already redirected

Tags: spring, http, redirect, grails

I use Grails 2.3.11 in my project.

I have next situation:

I have controller, that call redirect on exception:

```
class SomeController{
    someAction(){
        try {
            doSmth()
        } catch (exception) {
            return redirect (action: 'index')  //first redirect HERE
        }
    }
}
```

I have filter that also call redirect on another exception.

```
class BreadCrumbsFilters {


 def filters = {

        all(
                controller: '*',
                action: '*'
        ) {
            after = {
                if (request.xhr) return

                try {
                    buildBreadCrumbs()
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException) {
                    redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'auth') //second redirect HERE
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Redirect can not be called twice.

**Question**: How to check if there redirect was already called?

I found next solution:
Check response status.

```
if(response.status != 3**) redirect();
```

Is this method correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.3.11 you can call the following:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes

request.getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.REDIRECT_ISSUED)
```

That will return the redirect URI if a redirect has been issued and will return `null` if no redirect has been issued.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working fine!